# start and end time of yesterday in time-stamp python

Tags: python, linux, unix-timestamp

I want to get start time and end time of yesterday linux timestamp

```
import time
startDay = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
print startDay
endDay   =time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
print endDay
```

> Output is:
>
> 2016-11-18 00:00:00
>
> 2016-11-18 23:59:59

this showing in string today start-time and end-time
I want to get yesterday start-time and end-time in linux time-stamp
like:

> 4319395200
>
> 4319481599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import time
def datetime_timestamp(dt):
    time.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    s = time.mktime(time.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    return int(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
midnight2 = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0, microsecond=0)
midnight2 = midnight2 - datetime.timedelta(seconds= +1)
midnight1 = midnight2 - datetime.timedelta(days= +1, seconds= -1)
base = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
yesterday = (midnight1 - base).total_seconds()
thismorning = (midnight2 - base).total_seconds()
print midnight1,"timestamp",int(yesterday)
print midnight2,"timestamp",int(thismorning)
print "Seconds elapsed",thismorning - yesterday
```

Result as of 18/11/2016 :

```
2016-11-17 00:00:00 timestamp 1479337200
2016-11-17 23:59:59 timestamp 1479423599
Seconds elapsed 86399.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

# get start of today
dt = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(0, 0, 0))
# start of yesterday = one day before start of today
sday_timestamp = int((dt - timedelta(days=1)).timestamp())
# end of yesterday = one second before start of today
eday_timestamp = int((dt - timedelta(seconds=1)).timestamp())

print(sday_timestamp)
print(eday_timestamp)
```

Or:

```
# get timestamp of start of today
dt_timestamp = int(datetime.combine(date.today(), time(0, 0, 0)).timestamp())
# start of yesterday = start of today - 86400 seconds
sday_timestamp = dt_timestamp - 86400
# end of yesterday = start of today - 1 second
eday_timestamp = dt_timestamp - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of perl command , no need to import time.

Startday=$(perl -e 'use POSIX;print strftime "%Y-%-m-%d 00:00:00",localtime time-86400;')
Endday=$(perl -e 'use POSIX;print strftime "%Y-%-m-%d 23:59:59",localtime time-86400;')

echo $Startday 
echo $Endday

or

startday=`date --date='1 day ago' +%Y%m%d\t00:00:00`
startday=`date --date='1 day ago' +%Y%m%d\t23:59:59`

echo $Startday 
echo $Endday